# API does not appear

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Here's the image before
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wDOJ6.png)

and here's after

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PlnO9.png)

The API only appears and changes when submit to a different location but cannot work when submit on a different animal and breed

```js
useEffect(() => {
  requestPets();
}, []);

async function requestPets() {
  const res = await fetch(
    `http://pets-v2.dev-apis.com/pets?animal=${animal}&location=${location}&breed=${breed}`
  );
  const json = await res.json();
  setPets(json.pets);
}

<form
  onSubmit={(e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    requestPets();
  }}
>
<label htmlFor="location">
  Location
  <input
    onChange={(e) => setLocation(e.target.value)}
    type="text"
    id="location"
    value={location}
    placeholder="Location"
  />
  </label>
  <label htmlFor="animal">
    Animal
    <select
      name=""
      id="animal"
      value={animal}
      onChange={(e) => {
        setAnimal(e.target.value);
        setBreed("");
      }}
    >
      <option />
      {ANIMALS.map((animal) => (
        <option key={animal}>{animal}</option>
      ))}
    </select>
  </label>

  <label htmlFor="breed">
    Breed
    <select
      name=""
      disabled={breeds.length === 0}
      id="breed"
      value={breed}
      onChange={(e) => setBreed(e.target.value)}
    >
      <option />
      {breeds.map((breed) => (
        <option key={breed}>{breed}</option>
      ))}
    </select>
  </label>
  <button>Search</button>
</form>
```

I hope the API can appear and change as different animals and breeds when submit pressed.

Comment: Do you mean that you want the API to get called when changing dogs selected from selected box, or you mean that when changing dog and submit it didn't change?

Comment: yes I want when it submit it would change but it didn't

Answer (score 0):

Your `requestPets` function depends on various variables (`animal`, `location` and `breed`):

```js
async function requestPets() {
  const res = await fetch(
    `http://pets-v2.dev-apis.com/pets?animal=${animal}&location=${location}&breed=${breed}`
  );
  const json = await res.json();
  setPets(json.pets);
}
```

Since you are calling it through an `useEffect`, [you have to pass such variables to the dependency array](https://react.dev/reference/react/useEffect), in order to call the effect again when they change, like:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  requestPets();
}, [animal, location, breed]);
```

Comment: Thank you sir, but I want the flow API to appear when i press submit, not when i type location or change the animal/breed option

Comment: the flow for submit its work but its just for variable location, when i submit just variable animal or breed, the API does not appear

Comment: @maverick where are you using your `pets` variable? Show the relevant code so we can try to help ^^

Comment: its already solve sir thankss!